# jQuery draggable - what happens if it is applied twice to an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

Until recently I had this set up, which was called multiple times:

```
                $('.rsh')
                    .draggable('destroy')                               
                    .draggable({ blah blah details });
```

The `destroy` was there to stop multiple draggable handlers accumulating on the class. New elements are being created by AJAX, and an initial attachment of `draggable` to the class doesn't touch subsequently created elements.

However, when I updated to version 1.9.2 of jQuery UI, it started giving me this error:

> Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

So I removed the destroy line, and it's sweet. Except... I suspect that I may now be adding more and more handlers to the class (which is why the `destroy` was there in the first place).

I tried this, but it didn't like it:

```
if ($('.rsh').length) {
    $('.rsh').draggable('destroy'); 
}
```

Two questions: (1) Will there be more and more handlers attached to the class each time I fire the draggable set up line? (2) If so, any solutions on how to remove them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there won't be extra handlers bound. jQuery registers the initialized instance to the element and won't create a new instance of the same widget for the same element.

As you're worried about handlers, here's a quick check (jQuery 1.8+ and UI 1.9+):

```
$('div').draggable();
console.log( $._data($('div')[0], 'events') );
$('div').draggable();
console.log( $._data($('div')[0], 'events') );
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ByNuC/28/)

As you can see, the attached handlers object is not altered after trying to initialize a new draggable instance on the same element.

**edit:** Subsequent calls with parameters won't be ignored though, rather they will extend the existing widget as shown on @Jason Sperske's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Subsequent calls to `.draggable()` extend previous calls when attached to the same object (and not replace them as I had originally thought).  See this example (extended from Fabrício Matté's) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ByNuC/31/))

```
<div>foo</div>
<script>
 $('div').draggable({
  start: function () {
    console.log("drag 1");
  }
 });
 console.log($._data($('div')[0], 'events'));
 $('div').draggable({
  stop: function () {
    console.log("drag 2");
  }
 });
 console.log($._data($('div')[0], 'events'));
</script>
```

In the `console.log` you see only these messages:

```
drag 1 <- on start
drag 2 <- on stop
```

Comment: Oh nice, I forgot to consider the extending of the current widget. +1 for complementing it.