# jQuery dynamically created element with ID: what happens if the element already exists?

Tags: jquery

```
    var myWindow = $("<div id='msgwindow'/>").someWidget({
      option1: true,
      option2: someVariableWhoseValueChanges
     });
```

What happens if the code above is executed more than once? Does the element with id #msgwindow get completely or partially overwritten? Is it destroyed first and then re-created? Are there any vestiges hanging around from the previous instance?  What happens to any event listeners?

Comment: It should be fine see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248361/jquery-draggable-what-happens-if-it-is-applied-twice-to-an-element

Comment: @Christophe Roussy: thank you for that link.  I wonder if it would be better for the previous element to be removed from the DOM rather than extended.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your question does not apply `someWidget()` to an existing element. It creates a new `<div>` element and applies the widget to that new element (which may or may not result in appending the element to the page's `<body>`, depending on the widget).

Therefore, running this code several times will result in several elements being created and potentially added to the DOM. Since all these elements will share the same `id` attribute, that would make your document invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The element **will not get overwitten**. Simply, another element with the same ID will be created in the DOM.

As far as I'm aware, event listeners, such as `$("body").on("click", "#msgWindow"` will **only fire on the first instance of the element matching that ID in the DOM**.

You shouldn't really have multiple ID's in a document, it's bad practice, consider using a class.

Comment: or doing a check to see if the item exists already or give them dynamic id's

Comment: @mcgrailm Yeah, with a counter variable or something :)

Comment: I am not advocating the above approach, just wondering what the side-effects are.  I want a 'simpleton' object.