# best practice for opening and/or initializing jquery ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

There are two ways to open a jquery dialog:

1) Set the `autoOpen=true` when initializing a dialog

2) After initialization (with `autoOpen = false`), call `$("#id").dialog("open");`

At the moment, in my code, whenever a user clicks a button, a modal dialog opens by using the first method. On "Ok" or "Cancel" the dialog is closed `$(this).dialog("close");`

Is it bad that on every click the dialog is opened using autoOpen=true ? In other words, is it bad that the dialog is reinitialized on every click ?

From a performance, point of view, will reinitializing the dialog on every click cause problems such as dialog events being registered multiple times ?

What is the jquery best practice for this ?

Code:

```
$("#button").on("click",function(){

   $("#dialogHello").dialog({
      modal: true,
      autoOpen: true,
      buttons: [
        {   "text" : "Ok", "click" : function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
        {   "text" : "Cancel", "click" : function(){ $(this).dialog("close"); } }
      ]
   });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By observing the DOM, I noticed that the html elements that jquery ui dialog injects in the DOM are not duplicated if the jquery ui dialog is re-initialized on every call. If the jquery ui dialog DOM elements already exists then they are simply reused.

The following thread :

[jQuery draggable - what happens if it is applied twice to an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248361/jquery-draggable-what-happens-if-it-is-applied-twice-to-an-element)

Explains that the jquery events won't be registered several times on the same element if it already exists. For example, in my scenario, if I re-initialize the jquery ui dialog on every call then there won't be incrementing events being registered.

Answer (score 0):

I generally initialize my dialogs once with autoOpen set to false, and then 'open' them whenever they are needed. I'll possibly update the dialog content before opening if needed.

If for some reason you do feel the need to re-init it each time, then you should at least use the 'destroy' method first to avoid causing problems and bloat.

Comment: But does re-initializing truly bloat ?

I need help to establish hard evidence of that.

Comment: Looks like it at least adds additional html to the page: http://blog.balfes.net/2013/02/14/properly-cleaning-up-a-jquery-dialog-box-to-prevent-memory-leaks/ (though it might have changed in the year since then)

Comment: Yes it adds html but it doesn't keep adding. It reuses it if it already exists. As far as the DOM goes, if I reinitialize the jquery dialog every time, there doesn't seem to be any impact. Now, I'm just wondering about the dialog events. Are they registered multiple times when reinitialization is called multiple times? It doesn't appear so but it's hard to tell.

Comment: I just found this stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248361/jquery-draggable-what-happens-if-it-is-applied-twice-to-an-element It doesn't appear jquery registers many times the same events for the same element. The link talks about jquery draggable but I think it's applicable to jquery dialog. So, in the end, I'm still safe if I reinitialize it every time. It's a little less lines of code that way, even if it's not a recommended practice (generally speaking for any programming language). Thanks for your help John.